# No data is appearing in SSMS even though my job is running without errors

Tags: azure, containers, ssms, azure-application-insights, azure-stream-analytics

Problem: No data is appearing in SSMS (Sql Server Management Studio)

I don't see any errors appearing and my job diagram successfully shows a process from input to output.

I'm trying to use the continuous export feature of Azure Application Insights, Stream Analytics, and SQL Database.

Here is my query:

```sql
SELECT  
A.context.data.eventTime as eventTime,   
A.context.device.type as deviceType,  
A.context.[user].anonId as userId,  
A.context.device.roleInstance as machineName


INTO DevUserlgnsOutput -- Output Name

FROM devUserlgnsStreamInput A -- Input Name
```

I tested the query with sample data and the output box below the query and it returned what I expected, so I don't think the query itself is the issue.

I also know that the custom events I'm trying to display the attributes of have occurred since I began the job. My job is also still running and has not stopped since its creation.

In addition, I would like to point out that the monitoring graph on the stream analytics page detects 0 inputs, 0 outputs, and 0 runtime errors.

Thank you in advance for the help!

Below are some pictures that might help:

[Stream Analytics Output Details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YtRNU.png)
[The Empty SSMS after I clicked "display top 1000 rows," which should be filled with data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q0qAt.png)
[No input events, output events, or runtime errors for the stream analytics job](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6kz2i.png)

Comment: There would be some error messages if ASA encountered error while writing to output. For example, output may not  have all the columns or  the column types might be incompatible.

Comment: @VigneshChandramohan The output could be the problem, but there are also no input events detected by the stream analytics job (see "in addition...runtime errors" and the new picture I added). I would think, but I might not be correct, that the input would need to be working in order to check if the output is working.

Comment: can you check your events are being received at the source (Event Hub or IoT Hub)? Sampling input directly from you input (on the ASA job) might also help narrow down whether the events are flowing through. If there is an issue sampling from input, then it is likely an issue with events getting to the hub.

Comment: @user633659 That helped me. The input was the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had this issue twice with 2 separate application insights, containers, jobs, etc. Both times I solved this by editing the path pattern of my input(s) to my job.

To navigate to the necessary blade to make the following changes:

```
1) Click on your stream analytics job

2) Click "inputs" under the "job topology" section of the blade

3) Click your input (if multiple inputs, do this to 1 at a time)

4) Use the blade that pops up on the right side of the screen
```

The 4 potential solutions I've come across are ( A-D in **bold**):

**A. Making sure the path pattern you enter is plain text with no hidden characters (sometimes copying it from the container on Azure made it not plain text).**

```
*Steps:*

   1) Cut the path pattern you have already in the input blade

   2) Paste it into Notepad and re-copy it

   3) Re-paste it into the path pattern slot of your input
```

**B. Append your path pattern with /{date}/{time}**

```
Simply type this at the end of your path pattern in the blade's textbox
```

**C. Remove the container name and the "/" that immediately follows it from the beginning of your path pattern (see picture below)**

[Edit path pattern](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xeiy3.jpg)

```
Should be self-explanatory after seeing the pic.
```

**D. Changing the date format of your input to YYYY-MM-DD in the drop-down box.**

```
Should also be self-explanatory (look at the above picture if not).
```

Hope this helps!!